# How count online users without using database?

Tags: php

here is the code which I'm using to count online users but this is not working properly this count just 1 user every time. If that user is offline then this shows 0 users online. Please help why not this code working properly.

```
defined('MAX_IDLE_TIME') or define('MAX_IDLE_TIME', 10); 
class online {
    public static function who() {
        $path = session_save_path();
        if (trim($path)=="") {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $d = dir( $path); $i = 0;
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {       
            if ($entry!="." and $entry!="..") {
                if (time()- filemtime($path."/$entry") < MAX_IDLE_TIME * 10) {
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        $d->close();
        return $i;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "If that user is offline then this shows 0 users online"  that seems to be correct, because you want to count online users, and this one is offline ?

Comment: No, This shows just one user online every time even more than one user Online.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. How do you recognize that a user is online? Do you use a database and are looking for a way to avoid it or are you not using a database at all? Too much context is missing here.

Comment: @El_Vanja I'm guessing the OP is wanting to check all files in the session storage directory that are within a certain time-frame to see whether a user has updated a session file in that time.

Comment: You are just counting the number of files with a modification time less than MAX_IDLE_TIME. You could check (locally) if the answer of your function is correct or not